# 960px width: what about the small websites?

Tags: html, css

So I am making this personal website that has very litte content, and if I use the standard 960px width, there are very wide white spaces. It would be nice to have a shorter width, but then other problems arise such as bad view on other resolutions. What would you suggest?

Comment: If you insist on having a width, I would suggest `max-width`. Otherwise, dispense with the width altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To suit any screen resolution and make your website look good in any size, I would recommend going for a responsive design, using Media Queries. You can read up on the topic [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/).

That way, you can use 960px width for visitors with a browser window larger than that, and then make the website resize gracefully for visitors using mobile devices etc.

However, don't get too hung up on 960px width, that is no standard but simply a format that *often* works well, since 960 is a number that is easy do divide (to make columns) and is a width that is below the still quite common 1024px resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try **media queries**,    something like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)  href="shetland.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start thinking of building Responsive websites using CSS3 Media Queries.

I recommend the Skeleton CSS Framework ([link](http://www.getskeleton.com/)), pretty easy and lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on your webpage. And there are some standards for dimensions.

Check this: http://www.hobo-web.co.uk/best-screen-size/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use "position=relative" 
for every layer!!! this will eliminate your problem with width modifica